# H264 profile change using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, h.264, http-live-streaming

I have H264 Stream with following details

```
video stream type     :                 AVC  
resolution            :             640x368  
profile:level         :            High:4.0  
aspect ratio          :          40x23(1:1)  
chroma format         :               4:2:0  
interlaced            :                  no  
frames count          :                  15  
duration              :        00:00:02.800  
frame size max        :              80 088  
           avg        :              14 538  
       avg/max (I)    :     28 361 / 80 088  
       avg/max (P)    :       2 444 / 3 196  
       avg/max (B)    :               0 / 0  
           min        :               1 880  

framerate declared    :               5.000  
          real        :               5.000  

bitrate type          :                 VBR  
bitrate declared      :           1 259 968  

bit allocation max    :           1 126 640  
               avg    :             581 520  
               min    :             124 000
```

is it possible to convert into Baseline profile using FFMPEG or other tools, or is there a way to do myself?

basic idea is to stream this video to android devices.

Comment: You almost certainly want to re-encode the original source material instead of the h.264 stream you're giving the specs of.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg -i input_file.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k output_file.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Handbrake is an excellent tool, has a command line utility (which basically uses FFMpeg), and lists [here](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/BuiltInPresets) the commands to all their current profiles.

Considering you want a Baseline profile, the iPhone/iPod touch should do for you:

> ./HandBrakeCLI -i DVD -o ~/Movies/movie.mp4  -e x264 -q 20.0 -a 1 -E faac -B 128 -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 -f mp4 -X 480 -m -x cabac=0:ref=2:me=umh:bframes=0:weightp=0:subme=6:8x8dct=0:trellis=0